# disable hi-intensity white

Tags: windows-7

ever since i installed windows 7 on my lenovo T61 with nVidia graphics, the white background of documents, web pages, everything that is supposed to be white, are showing up dimmer than before. but my mouse cursor has a very bright white border.

it seems like windows 7 is trying to fake hi-intensity white by dimming white everywhere except the mouse cursor.

how can i disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in the Win7 Color Management. Either type "color managment" into the Windows search or find it in the control pannel.

I do not think that a color profile would dampen only specific things. A color profile would just set color parameters to try and standerdize the monitor. If your not used to having profiles, and didn't have one on the display before. That would be the first thing to check.

Comment: that was it. i picked the profile that matched my laptop's LCD panel and now everything is brighter.